# how to strip IP address of trailing string

Tags: regex, bash, cut

Given an IP address **192.168.10.21.somebody.com.br** 
I need to extract just **192.168.10.21** I tried CUT below, it gives "cut: invalid byte or field list".

> cut -d'.' -f-4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ echo "192.168.10.21.somebody.com.br" | cut -d'.' -f -4
192.168.10.21
```

works for me!

Answer (score 4):

All three of the following assume you have the domain name stored in a parameter

```
dom_name=192.168.10.21.somebody.com.br
```

More efficient than using `cut`, assuming the first label to remove doesn't start with a number:

```
echo "${dom_name%%.[[:alpha:]]*}"
```

If the first label *could* start with a number, these are still more efficient than `cut`, but uglier and much longer to type:

```
# Match one more dot than necessary to shorten the regular expression;
# then trim that dot when echoing
[[ $dn =~ (([0-9]+\.){4}) ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]%.}"
```

or

```
# Split the string into an array, then output the
# first four fields rejoined by dots.
IFS=. read -a labels <<< "$dom_name"
(IFS=.; echo "${labels[*]:0:4}")
```